# How to Solve Null Pointer exception i my code?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

When i run my java code:

```
public class LalaLuLu {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{ 
        String path = "D:/Gem/FINAL/Datatest.csv";
        File file = new File(path);
        InputStream is;
        System.out.println(file.exists());

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        PrintWriter os = new PrintWriter ( new FileOutputStream("D:/Gem/FINAL/out_datatest1.txt"));
        String output = "";
        int count = 0;
        do{
            output = br.readLine();
            String[] a = output.split(";");
            System.out.println("total kolom: " + a.length);
            os.println(output);
            System.out.println(count++ );
        } while (!output.equals(""));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} }
```

When i run, the error on this line :

```
output = br.readLine();
String[] a = output.split(";");
```

And error I am getting is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at DAO.readdata.readdataCSV(readdata.java:47)
```

Can you tell me how to solve this error? Thank you

Comment: What is there at line 47, did you check value of that variable in debugger ? If yes what is that value.

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs for how `readLine()` works: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine().

> A String containing the contents of the line, not
>   including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the
>   stream has been reached

It is reading the end of the file and returning `null`.

The simplest fix would be the following

```
 do{
     output = br.readLine();
     if (output == null ) {
         break;
     }
     String[] a = output.split(";");
     System.out.println("total kolom: " + a.length);
     os.println(output);
     System.out.println(count++ );
 } while (!output.equals(""));
```

Comment: It helps me. Thank you for your solution.